# Regular Classes in Servlets

Tags: java, servlets

i want to use my regular class in servlet, but i always get an classnotfountException
i am trying something like this

```
      protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      try {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Searchpatient"));
        Hospital h = new Hospital();
        h.searchPatient(id);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

WebAppllication

- Web Pages

  Web-INF

  ```
   classes

       hospital.java
  ```
- Source packages.

  - Controller.

    -NewServlet
- libraries

Comment: The code is OK. Your problem is in deployment. Please explain how do you run your servlet.

Comment: first i run JSP page and then it requests a servlet

Comment: I mean something else. How do you deploy your web application? Do you use war?

Comment: i use netbeans to deploy web application, i am new to java so doesn't know much about that !

Comment: @user3623843 your classes must be available in the web application WEB-INF/lib in a jar or in WEB-INF/classes (if it's not in a jar). These are the default classpath for a web app.

Comment: @Leo , and where to place my servlet ??

Comment: Please update your post, and show/describe the layout of your project. Where your regular classes are located? What folder did you use for this purpose ?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov , here it is

Answer (score 1):

OK, I see. Typically various graphical tools work, however if they do not you should understand how is web application built and what does it mean "deploy web application."

Web application is a bunch of files either located in file system or packaged in war file that is ordinary zip that however has special structure.

All resources directly available from web are typically located in the root. For example jsps, HTMLs etc. If they are stored in folder the HTTP path should reflect this fact. There is special folder named `WEB-INF`. This folder contains web application descriptor `web.xml`, and optionally folder `classes` and folder `libs`. Folder `classes` contains plain java classes (i.e. files with extension `*.class`). Filder `libs` contains jar files (i.e. zip files that contain classes inside).

All these is typically contained under special application folder of your container.

Now, what does NetBeans do? It creates file structure required by java web applications spec and copies it under your application container. Then it runs the container and connects to it with remote debugger.

So, I guess that your class does not exist in `classes` folder. Check this fact. If it is correct check why NetBeans fails to copy it. I believe that the cause is in your project dependencies or something like this. Check your project properties, etc.

Good luck.

Comment: i just edited my question and showed my web application structure, can you please tell me that now how can i get classes in WEB-INF/classes, in my servlet. or in other words how to import them in my newServlet.java class.

Comment: Is your class' name `hospital.java` or `Hospital.java`? java is case sensitive. And does it probably belong to any package? Because according to your file structure it does not.

Comment: Wait! Why `hospital.java`? You need compiled class, i.e. `hospital.class`

Comment: i have now added all the compiled classes to the folder u mentioned.
but now tomcat hangs saying that
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [NewServlet] in context with path [/WebApplication11] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at mypackage.Hospital.SearchPatient(Hospital.java:118)
 at controller.NewServlet.processRequest(NewServlet.java:45)
 at controller.NewServlet.doGet(NewServlet.java:78)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

Comment: Dear @user3623843, NPE is thrown from Hospital.java, line 118. Check your code and try to understand why does it happen. Something is not initialized there. But may I give you an advice? I am sorry to say this but you are trying to drive formula 1 without any basic driving skills. Start learning java. First start from core java, then go forward to web programming. Otherwise each your step will be extremely difficult.